# Flutter doctor -android sdk file not found in platform/android-29

Tags: flutter

I have already install flutter and **android studio**, but when I executed flutter doctor ,

```
doctor found issues 
android sdk file not found in path
 ( AppDate\local\android\sdk\platform\android-29\android.jar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the Virtual devices manager in the Android Studio emulator, and download android SDK versions from it, you will have the download options, and then it will work.

1. Click here:

[image: List item]

2. After here:

[image]

3. Select any Device:

[image]

4. Choose which android version to download.

[image: List item]

This will install the desired versions.

Answer (score 0):

AppDate\local\android\sdk\platform\android-29\android.jar

Go to this path and make sure files are not deleted.

[Folder should have such files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnpUD.png)


If It is empty then install it!
open android studio goto File>Settings>Appearance and Behaviour>System Setting>Android SDK

Click on api 29 and download

[Make sure android api 29 is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJiXs.png)

Answer (score 0):

AppDate\local\android\sdk\platform\android-29\android.jar
Go to this path and make sure files are not deleted.
Folder should have such files

If It is empty then install it!
open android studio goto File>Settings>Appearance and Behaviour>System Setting>Android SDK
Click on api 29 and download
Make sure android api 29 is installed